# Binding text value in html element using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a popup div containing an error message that I want to generate at the time the popup actually pops up. In my popup `div` I have a `p`tag where its text is databinded to a function that returns a string (the error message). I've done similar things before with much success, but this time I'm struggling to successfully bind the value properly.
The HTML div (ignore the jQuery Mobile attributes):

```
<div data-role="popup" id="ErrorRowValidation" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" class="standarddialog" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <p data-bind="text: $root.getModelErrorText.bind($root)" class="validationError"></p>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-bind="click: $root.correctRowValue.bind($root)" data-theme="a">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.undoValidation.bind($root)" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Undo changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript (actually typescript) function successfully returns a proper string, so that's not the problem, but here it is anyway:

```
public getModelErrorText(): string {
    return lang.translateNewlineString(this.model.ErrorText());
}
```

I think I'm not binding the text value correctly when writing `data-bind="text: $root.getModelErrorText.bind($root)"`..?
With the code above I get `function() {[native code]}` as a result. I've also tried doing `data-bind="text: $root.getModelErrorText()"` with no success; the page won't even load then.
I'm new to using Knockout, so I don't really know what I'm doing... Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your ViewModel? Did you call `ko.applyBindings()` ?

Comment: Yes. I've done similar things many times before, but without actually fully understanding how it works... I usually bind the value as I tried above and that works fine, just not in this case. I'm 99% my ViewModel is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I'm not binding the text value correctly when writing
>   `data-bind="text: $root.getModelErrorText.bind($root)"`

Indeed, this is not correct and will result in `function() {[native code]}`

`bind` doesn't execute your function, it just creates a new function with a different execution context (this may or may not be slightly improperly formulated by me, but I am 100% sure the function is not executed).

`data-bind="text: $root.getModelErrorText()"` SHOULD work, if all other things work. So I'm not 100% sure why this doesn't work for you. We'd need additional information to debug that (more code, e.g. your viewModel, html and `applyBindings` call). One good bet, is that `this` in your function `getModelErrorText` is not set to the viewModel when executed through the binding. You can easily see if this is the problem, by transforming the function to `fat arrow syntax`, like this:

```
public getModelErrorText = () => {
    return lang.translateNewlineString(this.model.ErrorText());
}
```

This should guarantee that `this` points to your viewModel.

If this does not resolve the problem, can you edit your post with the code I mentioned above, and I will edit my answer as well.

### Edit:

Another possibility, is that `this.model` or `this.model.ErrorText` is not yet a truthy value (e.g. it is `null` or `undefined`) when the bindings are applied. In that case, `this.model.ErrorText()` will fail, since you are trying to execute a function (observable) that does not yet exist, because it is initialized at a later point in time. Make sure the default values in your viewModel have a properly set `model` with `ErrorText` function/observable. When your page doesn't load, try looking in the `developer tools -> console` to see if Knockout gives you an error message. It will probably be helpful if you post it here.

Comment: What you mention in your edit is actually very possible! I have a getModel() that is asynchronous, meaning the value might very well be null when the bindings are actually applied. I'll try changing that :)

Comment: Returning "test" from my js function works fine, so I think you're on to something...
I otherwise get the following errors:
"Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return $root.getModelErrorText() }"
Message: Cannot read property 'ErrorText' of undefined"
"Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."  
I'll try setting the text value from my script instead, then I can make sure it's only binded once the value IS a truthy value.

Comment: Yes! Setting the text value from within my script AFTER the actual validation process (which is asynchronous) worked! Just as you said, `this.model.ErrorText()` simply was undefined at the time I tried applying the bindings. Thank you very much; it was a simple fix to an ignorant mistake from my hand, but you got me on the right track of thought :)